# php: When is a null array element not null?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to detect when an array element is null, but `is_null` isn't doing the job. In detail, I'm sending some POST data to a server, where the JavaScript object sent has no value:

```
$.ajax({
 type:     "POST",
 url:      "comms.php",
 data:     {practice:tab_content},   // array 'tab_content' has not been set
 dataType: "script"
});
```

In the server php code, I need to check whether 'practice' has a value (if it doesn't, I get an error when using foreach to cycle through the 'practice' array).

`print_r($_POST)` in the php code shows:

```
Array
(
   [practice] => null 
)
```

Here's my test program which checks what $_POST["practice"] actually is:

```
<?php
$params = "";
if(array_key_exists("practice", $_POST))
   $params .= "array_key_exists true;";
else
   $params .= "array_key_exists false;";

if(is_null($_POST["practice"]))
   $params .= " is_null true;";
else
   $params .= " is_null false;";

if(isset($_POST["practice"]))
   $params .= " isset true;";
else
   $params .= " isset false;";

if(empty($_POST["practice"]))
   $params .= " empty true;";
else
   $params .= " empty false;";

$params .= " value is '" . $_POST["practice"] . "'.";
$output  = "document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML=\"";
$output .= $params;
$output .= "\";\n";
echo $output;
?>
```

The client output is identical on Opera and Chrome, and is:

```
array_key_exists true; is_null false; isset true; empty false; value is 'null'.
```

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks.

### EDIT 22:10GMT

Thanks everybody - that's fixed it. Using var_dump did give the necessary information, as a  couple of you suggested:

```
array(1) {
  ["practice"]=>
  string(4) "null"
}
```

And, if I modified the ajax call to send a string containing "null", then I got exactly the same effect. This is pretty strange, though - why does XMLHttpRequest send through a completely valid string containing n-u-l-l for an empty value? That makes it pretty difficult to send through a real n-u-l-l. Given this confusion, I'm using is_array, as benjam suggested.
Thanks - love this site :)

Comment: what exactly is your question? im having a hard time understanding what you want to know

Comment: Everything passing with POST is a string. Even "null"

Comment: *"value is 'null'"* - That doesn't seem right to me. `$foo = NULL; print "-$foo-";` prints `--`, not `-null-`.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to obtain more information about the value in question.

Comment: You can't sent a "real" null, because data is sent with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which has no datatypes--all parameter names and values are strings. If you want to send a real null, you need to send JSON or some other format that has a concept of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `is_array($_POST["practice"])`, that way, you will know it's an array, and `foreach` will never throw errors.

Answer (score 5):

Do a var_dump($_POST) instead, it shows you the varaible's type and size as well as content.

Basically anything coming out of _GET/_POST/_REQUEST is a string. A field which existed in the form, but had no data in it, will come out as an empty string. Your null value is not an actual php "null", it's a literal string whose value is n-u-l-l.

Given a php script like this:

```
<pre>
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
</pre>

<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="">
</form>
```

clicking submit will get you this:

```
array(2) {
  ["submit"]=>
  string(12) "Submit Query"
  ["hidden"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Note that the 'hidden' field exists, and has a 0-length string as its value. That means:

```
array_key_exists('hidden', $_POST); -> true
isset($_POST['hidden']); -> true
empty($_POST['hidden']); -> true
is_null($_POST['hidden']); -> false
```

Comment: You can have arrays coming out of _GET/_POST/_REQUEST, but in this instance, you are correct.  The value is a string literal "null".  Checking `is_array( )` will catch that, and return a false.

Answer (score 2):

As @racar mentioned in a comment, if something is coming from the browser, then the data type is always `string`, except for `array` post values which will be an array of strings.

If you are seeing `null`, when you print it, that means it is literally a string containing the word "null".

So, for your example here, you need to be doing:

```
if ($_POST["practice"] == "null") {
  ...
}
```